# (myservicename)/cloudapp.net is not responding

Tags: java, azure-cloud-services

I have successfully published my first azure deployment project by using java eclipse as cloud service and i got a working url. Although my next cloud service created successfully, the url (.../cloupapp.net) did not bring me to apache tomcat page. Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you RDP onto the VM in Azure? (if you enabled remote desktop when you deployed you can do this from the Azure management website - it will download an RDP file to connect with. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh690951.aspx) for help)

Once you can RDP onto the machine then check everything is configured as you expect with tomcat, and that you can browse the website locally.